# Oracle Separation Survey

Tags: computational-complexity

Is there a survey (or a website) somewhere that lists all known separation results?

I.e. it has a list of triples:

$$ (C_1, C_2, A)$$

where

```
1. We do not know if $C_1 = C_2$
2. We know that $C_1^A = C_2^A$ or $C_1^A \neq C_A^A$
```

I.e. I'm looking for a big list, for classes like:

L vs P. P vs NP. BPP vs NEXP. etc ...

Comment: I second JDH's suggestion of the Complexity Zoo, though, from what I can tell, it will require you to compile the answers yourself by going through all the 495 classes listed there. On the plus side, I would tend to trust the zoo to have even the latest results, and the zookeepers are very good with providing references for everything. The site was created specifically because few people can confidently remember such long lists of separation results. 

Comment: By the way, I'm sure there must be surveys too. They will be more reader-friendly, but less comprehensive, by definition. In the long run, you probably want to look at both.

Comment: Is there a general definition, given a class $C$ of languages, what the relativized class $C^A$ means for oracle $A$? This notation seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

The [Complexity Zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo) compiles a huge amount of the information you want, if not exactly in the form you request.

Answer (score 3):

The [Complexity Zoology](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/) gives you exactly what you are looking for.